# How to pass a href link created in java to jsp page

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently i am using a bootstrap alerts to display errors or information in my JSP.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times; 
    </a>
    <label class="control-label" style="color: #FF0000"><strong>Error:</strong>
      <c:out value="${errorMsg}"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

There is a requirement to include links in my error messages.So i have formed a href link in server side(JAVA) and passed the info to the client side(JSP).

```
String link = "<a href=\"http://microsoft.com\" target=\"_blank\">microsoft</a>";

String errorMsg = "Test error : " + link  + "Ignore";
request.setAttribute("errorMsg",errorMsg);
```

But on the jsp page , it is directly displaying the `<a></a>` tag instead of showing it as the link.

i tried different ways to pass the error message , but still end up with the same issue.

Can anyone enlighten me on what am i doing wrong or any possible ways to handle it better?

P.S: the above code is not a working code and is added for delineation purpose.

Thanks for your suggestions and time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `escapeXML=false`

```
<c:out value="${errorMsg}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

More details here: http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/jstl/jstl-core-tag-out